# Actionscript: compare variables from an array

Tags: actionscript, compare

Need Help, I have totalA - totalB - totalC - totalD, need to select the highest variable from this 4 but if the highest one equal an other one, must show which variables equals.

I have used this code but when it meets the equals ( A = B = C ) it dispalys just D

```
var aNumber:Array = new Array(totalA , totalB , totalC , totalD );

for(var i:Number = 0; i < aNumber.length; i++)
{
    if(aNumber[i] < aNumber[i+1]) 
    {
        bigger = aNumber[i+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear .

Comment: `totalA - totalB - totalC - totalD` What are these ?

Comment: Just a total from 4 scores

Comment: can you put same sample values for this total vars ?

Comment: Hi Adrian, yes totalA,B,C,D can have the same value that's the prb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to output a letter/etc for the scores, I'd use an object/dictionary rather than a straight array.

Basically, the algorithm would be:

- Capture the scores in an object/dictionary, where the key is the name of the player and the value is their score.
- Enumerate each item/player in the object/dictionary and compare the current score to the maximum score.
- If the current score is greater than the maximum score, clear all previous winners, set the new maximum score and add the current player to the winners.
- If the current score is equal to the maximum score, add the current player to the winners array.

Following is some hastily concocted actionscript.

```
var scores:Object = {
    'A': totalA,
    'B': totalB,
    'C': totalC,
    'D': totalD
};

var maxScore:Number = -1;
var winners:Array = new Array();

for(var player:String in scores)
{
    var score:Number = scores[player];

    if (score > maxScore)
    {
        maxScore = score;

        winners = new Array();
        winners.push(player);
    }
    else if (score == maxScore)
    {
        winners.push(player);
    }
}
```

At the end of this segment of code, you should have the highest score in `maxScore` and the names of the winning players in the `winners` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var aNumber:Array = new Array(totalA , totalB , totalC , totalD );
bigger = aNumber[0];
for(var i:Number = 1, var j:Number = (aNumber.length)-1; i<j ; i++)
{
    if(bigger < aNumber[i]) 
    {
        bigger = aNumber[i];
    }
}
var highest:Array = new Array();
highest[] = bigger;
for(var i:Number = 0, var j:Number = (aNumber.length); i<j ; i++){
   if(aNumber[i] == bigger){
     highest[] = aNumber[i];
   }
}
```

Array highest will now hold the highest score(s)

Comment: Thanks, and how can I get the draw scores ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. How to output the values of `highest`?

Answer (score 0):

This solution can be a bit more elegant (assuming that a array contains integer values):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.Sort;
            import mx.collections.SortField;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private var array:Array = [1,2,3,4,3];

            public function init():void{
                var maxValue:Number = getMaxValue(new ArrayCollection(array));
                Alert.show(String(maxValue)); //show value 4
            }

            private function getMaxValue(tempArr:ArrayCollection):Number { 
                var dataSort:Sort    = new Sort(); 
                dataSort.fields        = [new SortField(null,false,true,true)];; 
                tempArr.sort = dataSort; 
                tempArr.refresh(); 
                return tempArr[0];
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

According to this example, I order the array from highest to lowest and take the first. Its works perfectly. I hope this helps